# How to work with Nested ArrayLists in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have the following vb.net code

```
    Dim k As New List(Of String)
    Dim a As New List(Of List(Of String))
       For fc = 1 To 2
          k.add("hi")
          k.add("hey")
          k.add("bye")
          a.add(k)
          k.clear()

 ########Printing Stuff

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To a.Count - 1
        Dim sstr As String
        For Each sstr In a.Item(i)
            MsgBox(sstr)
        Next
    Next i
```

For some reason my code passes right through the printing code without outputting anything at all. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way of doing it?  Ofcourse what I add to k is simplfied here but it is a string.

Comment: Did you know that the `ArrayList` class is obsolete? It's been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use the strongly-typed `List<T>` class instead. If absolutely necessary, use `List<object>`.

Comment: Can I still use add if I use the list class? Because I am not sure how many elements my array/arraylist will contain  Edit: Nvm I still can Thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course. I wouldn't have told you to use `List` if you couldn't do the same things with it as you could with `ArrayList`.

Comment: Updated with List. Still nothing pops up?

Comment: Don't do the k.clear. Just do `k = new List(Of String)` in each loop.

Comment: If you would put your answer in Answer so I could accept it, would be great :). It worked. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do the `k.clear`. Just do `k = new List(Of String)` in each loop.